# What to do when a registrar goes out of business?

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar

A friend of mine registered a domain name at a host called [ServWeb](http://www.servwebsolutions.com), which now appears to be out of business (just a guess; as you can see there's no response from ServWeb's site.).  ServWeb apparently registered the domain via [Enom](http://www.enom.com), but Enom won't do anything without approval from ServWeb.

What recourse does my friend have to regain control over their domain?

Answer (score 1):

If your friend (or friend's business/organization) is listed as the registrant on the domain registration, most registrars have a manual process for allowing the registrant to (re)gain control over their domain name. This typically involves some form of photo identification, formal request on company letterhead, or some other means of your friend proving he truly is the owner of the domain.

However, if ServWeb registered the domain in their own name, your friend may have little recourse, because as far as eNom is concerned, ServWeb would be the registrant. If ServWeb just closed up shop, I suppose there's an outside chance your friend may be able to contact someone who used to work there that could still login to eNom to help him out. On the other hand, if ServWeb filed for bankruptcy and creditors are dividing up the remaining assets, the domain names registered in their name could be considered assets to be sold or auctioned to cover any of ServWeb's remaining liabilities.

Has your friend actually tried to contact or visit ServWeb to verify that they really are out of business?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that they've gone out of business because their web site is down is a pretty big leap if you ask me. Have you or your friend tried phoning or emailing them?

Comment: The site has apparently been down from several weeks, along with the sites they host. If they're not out of business now, they will be soon.

Answer (score 0):

I myself am in the same situation and have lost all contact with my web provider. I have been told however that if you can prove that you are the legal owner of the business and that the domain address is directly linked to the operation of the business then you may be considered the rightful owner of your domain address even if you are not the listed registrant.  You may need to enlist the help of a solicitor for this. You may also like to seek help from the Department of Fair Trading.  If you do ever manage to contact your web provider you will need to obtain a registration key from them and ask them to unlock the domain. I'm at my wits end, so good luck to your friend.